# Drawing text in .NET with native look & feel

Tags: .net, winforms, text, drawing

I'm using .NET1 and I want to draw text as native. Is it possible by configuring graphics?

I need to render the text as the System.Windows.Forms.Label does when the FlatStyle is set to System.

I have configured the SmoothingMode and the AntiAliasGridFit, but unfortunately the result is not the same:

[image]

I'm using the same font in both cases (Segoe UI 9pt).

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you rendering the text? In .Net1.1 I'm assuming you're using Graphics.DrawString? Maybe you should look at calling the native "DrawTextEx" function if DrawString is not producing the desired formatting.

Comment: This was solved 4 major releases of .NET ago.  Kinda pointless to teach that old dog new tricks.

Comment: @Hans Maybe he has a specific target platform requirement? In an ideal world we'd all be using the latest and greatest of everything. Given, 1.1 is ancient, but so is IE6 and sadly that's still a required target platform in a lot of real-world cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`TextRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.aspx) class instead of the `Graphics.DrawString` routine? It was introduced into the framework precisely because there is a discrepancy between the default rendering of Windows Forms and .NET’s GDI+ wrapper.

The MSDN says:

> The TextRenderer class provides a set of static methods that can be used for measuring and drawing text on a Windows Form control.

Comment: I believe the "TextRenderer" class is only available in 2.0 and greater versions of the framework. He's explicitly stating .Net 1.1.

Comment: @Brandon: ouch, didn’t see. But to be blunt, that is an unreasonable requirement and I would *strongly* advise an immediate platform switch, *before* doing any other work.

Comment: Well, I hate developing in .NET 1.1 but it's a requeriment for me. We need to support an integration with Visual Studio 2003 that is incompatible with .NET 2.0 or higher.